# Create barplot from data.frame

Tags: r, plot, dataframe

In R I have a data.frame like the one on the top of the picture.

Is there a possibility to create a barplot like below?

data.frame:

```
      X1   X2   X3  
 --- ---- ---- ---- 
  A    2   3    4   
  B    4   2    1   
  C    1   NA   NA
```

Barplot:

```
----------------------------
|                          |
|       #    #             |
|    #  #    #             |
| #  #  #    #  #          |
| #  #  #    #  #  #    #  |
----------------------------
  X1 X2 X3   X1 X2 X3   x1
     A           B       C
```

Comment: If you mean an ascii output try the `txtplot` package.

Comment: Sorry, this was just an example ;) i want to have a plot like the one i get with the barplot function

Comment: Probably you want to change the titel of your question? You actually want to create a barplot from a data.frame and not vice versa.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Using base graphics you can do this simply:

```
mydf <- data.frame( X1=c(A=2, B=4, C=1), X2=c(3,2,NA), X3=c(4,1,NA) )
barplot(t(as.matrix(mydf)), beside=TRUE)
```

Using additional calls to `axis` can give the labeling more like in the question.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer - why use two libraries to do such a simple task?

Comment: because converting to a matrix and then a table could add a lot of overhead if you have a large df?

Comment: @wordsforthewise, if the df is so large that this overhead is even noticible (let alone a problem) then a barplot is probably not the best visualization of it anyways.

Answer (score 20):

Assuming, that you don't want ascii output, here is a solution using `ggplot2`:

```
# load / generate your data
mydf <- data.frame( X1 = c(2,4,1), X2 = c(3,2,NA), x3 = c(4,1,NA), row.names=c("A","B","C") )
mydf$Category  <- row.names(mydf)

# bring your data to long format as needed by ggplot
library(reshape2)
mydf.molten <- melt(mydf, value.name="Count", variable.name="Variable", na.rm=TRUE)

# plot and facet by categories
library(ggplot2)
qplot( data=mydf.molten, x = Variable, y = Count, geom="bar", stat = "identity" ) + facet_wrap( "Category" )
```

[image]

For further details, I'd recommend to consult the [ggplot2 manual](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/), especially the chapter about [`geom_bar`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html) and [`facet_wrap`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/facet_wrap.html).

Comment: got this error with your code:
`> mydf.molten <- melt(mydf, value.name="Count", variable.name="Variable", na.rm=TRUE)
Using Category as id variables
> qplot( data=mydf.molten, x = Variable, y = Count, geom="bar", stat = "identity" ) + facet_wrap( "Category" )
Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
In addition: Warning message:
`stat` is deprecated `

Comment: @Mona Jalal; `ggplot2` has changed since 2013, especially when it upgraded from ver. 1.xxx to 2.xxx.