# Split barplot by grouping by days

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the following bar chart produced using this code:

```
MD1<-read.csv("MD_qual_OTU_sorted.csv")

MD1<-data.frame(Samples=c("A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M", "N","O","P","Q", "R"), Number.of.OTUs=c(13,10,9,9,15,11,7,7,9,9,5,10,10,7,15,17,8,9))
par(las=1)

barplot(MD1[,2],names.arg=MD1[,1], ylab='OTU Count', yaxt='n', xlab='MD samples', main='Total OTU count/Sample',density=c(90,90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40), col=c("yellow","yellow","pink", "pink","green","green","red","red", "purple", "purple", "blue", "blue", "orange", "orange","cyan", "cyan","chartreuse4", "chartreuse4" ))
```

[image]

```
usr <- par("usr")
par(usr=c(usr[1:2], 0, 20))
axis(2, at=seq(0,20,5))
```

I want to split samples A-F into a separate group (Day 3), G-L (Day 5) and M-R (Day 15)

There are similar questions posted however I am not sure how to tidy up the manner in which I have inputted my data to be able to use these solutions.

Comment: What do you want to do with the grouping? Create separate plots? Or create space between groups?

Comment: I would like to split it so that day3 is a separate plot, day 5 is separate and day 15 is separate. MD samples will still be my x axis title but day3, day5 and day15 will be sub-titles, kind of like this plot. So yeah create a space between the groups. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617365/create-barplot-from-data-frame.

Comment: one-liner (if you dont count generating the data) `h <- letters[1:18]; barplot(seq_along(h), space = c(.1,.5)[h %in% c('g','m') + 1], names.arg = h)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using ggplot2, separate plots are very easy using `facet_wrap` and `facet_grid`.

```
library(ggplot2)


#create a grouping variable
MD1$Day <- rep(c("Day 03","Day 05","Day 15"),
               each=6)

p1 <- ggplot(MD1, aes(x=Samples,y=Number.of.OTUs)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity") + facet_wrap(~Day,
                                         scales="free_x")
p1
```

[image]

Or, if you want to use base-R and approach your original image:
    #add colors/densities

```
MD1$col <-  c("yellow","yellow","pink", "pink","green","green","red","red", 
              "purple", "purple", "blue", "blue", "orange", "orange","cyan", "cyan","chartreuse4", "chartreuse4" )
MD1$density <- c(90,90, 90, 90, 90, 90, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40)

#set 1 row three cols for plotting
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
#split and plot
lapply(split(MD1, MD1$Day),function(x){
  barplot(x[,2],
          names.arg=x[,1],
          ylab='OTU Count',
          ylim=c(0,20),
          main=unique(x$Day),
          col=x$col,
          density=x$density)
})
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful :)