# Plot multiple columns in r with barplot

Tags: r, dataframe, bar-chart

How do I plot a bar graph using data from 3 columns in a dataframe read from a csv file? I tried doing it with the following code but had some difficulty getting my desired output:

```
setwd("\\path\\to\\csv")
df = read.csv("xxxx.csv")

# All hospitals in AL
AL = df[grep("AL", df$State),]

hos <-subset(AL,Hospital.Name=='COOPER GREEN MERCY HOSPITAL')


# Gives me "Error in -0.01 * height : non-numeric argument to binary operator"

hos <- data.frame (HeartAttack=hos$Heart.Attack.Mortality,HeartFailure=hos$Heart.Failure..Mortality,
                   Pneumonia=hos$Pneumonia.Mortality)

# Gives me the graph without displaying the x-axis values 
# but completely defeats the purpose of reading from a csv file since the values are hard-written

#hos <- data.frame (HeartAttack=c(1),HeartFailure=c(5),Pneumonia=c(10))

barplot(t(as.matrix(hos)),main='Mortality Rate in Cooper Green Mercy Hospital',
        xlab='Illness',ylab='Mortality Rate',beside=TRUE)
```

The csv file has 10 headers (from left to right): Hospital.Name, City, State, County.Name, **Heart.Attack.Mortality**, Heart.Attack.Readmission, **Heart.Failure..Mortality**, Heart.Failure.Readmission, **Pneumonia.Mortality** and Pneumonia.Readmission. Bold ones are the columns I'm interested in.

[image: Desired output]

Note: I have already looked at these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617365/create-barplot-from-data-frame) [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37931327/barplot-with-multiple-columns-in-r), but they did not quite solve my problem.

Comment: We don't have access to your disk file so the code that creates `hos` is not reproducible. Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(hos)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(hos, 20))`.

Comment: If you're not hell-bent on base plot, you could use [`ggplot2::geom_col`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_bar.html). You can use `tidyr::gather` to reflow columns into a variable:value pair.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I've provided the csv file in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data has `"Not Available"` instead of `NA` in numeric columns so those columns become of class `"factor"` (if `stringsAsFactors = TRUE`, the default) or of class `"character"` (if `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`). I have therefore run the following right after reading in the data.

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {
  is.na(x) <- x == "Not Available"
  x})

i <- sapply(df, function(x) {
  y <- as.numeric(as.character(x))
  !all(is.na(y))
})

df[i] <- lapply(df[i], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Another, better, possibility is to read the data in with

```
df = read.csv("xxxx.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE, na.strings = "Not Available")
```

Then comes your data preparation code.

Now the plot. The `space` argument is needed to make room for the middle bar label.

```
barplot(t(as.matrix(hos)),
            main = 'Mortality Rate in Cooper Green Mercy Hospital',
            xlab = 'Illness', ylab = 'Mortality Rate',
            names.arg = names(hos),
            beside = TRUE,
            space = c(0.05, 0))
```

[image]